# Merge several json arrays in circe

Tags: json, scala, circe

Let's say we have 2 json arrays. How to merge them into a single array with circe? Example:

Array 1:

```
[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}]
```

Array 2:

```
[{"id": 4}, {"id": 5}, {"id": 6}]
```

Needed:

```
[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}, {"id": 4}, {"id": 5}, {"id": 6}]
```

I've tried `deepMerge`, but it only keeps the contents of the argument, not of the calling object.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose we've got the following set-up (I'm using circe-literal for convenience, but your `Json` values could come from anywhere):

```
import io.circe.Json, io.circe.literal._

val a1: Json = json"""[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}, {"id": 3}]"""
val a2: Json = json"""[{"id": 4}, {"id": 5}, {"id": 6}]"""
```

Now we can combine them like this:

```
for { a1s <- a1.asArray; a2s <- a2.asArray } yield Json.fromValues(a1s ++ a2s)
```

Or:

```
import cats.std.option._, cats.syntax.cartesian._

(a1.asArray |@| a2.asArray).map(_ ++ _).map(Json.fromValues)
```

Both of these approaches are going to give you an `Option[Json]` that will be `None` if either `a1` or `a2` don't represent JSON arrays. It's up to you to decide what you want to happen in that situation `.getOrElse(a2)` or `.getOrElse(a1.deepMerge(a2))` might be reasonable choices, for example.

As a side note, the current contract of `deepMerge` says the following:

> Null, Array, Boolean, String and Number are treated as values, and values from the argument JSON completely replace values from this JSON.

This isn't set in stone, though, and it might not be unreasonable to have `deepMerge` concatenate JSON arrays—if you want to open an issue we can do some more thinking about it.